# Vector of RegEnable

Tags: chisel

Looking for an example/advice on how to use RegEnable as vector.
Also I want to control the inputs & enable signals to be a function of the register  index in the Vector.

So first, how do I declare Vector of RegEnable(), and second how to iterate over it and connect the input & enable. In the RegEnable() case the declaration and the connection are made in the same statement. Something like:

```scala
for (j <- 0 until len) {
    val pipe(j) = RegEnable(in(j),en(j))    
}
```

The above code doesn't compile. Also in & en are vectors or bit selection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this type of thing, it's likely much easier to use `RegEnable` to construct a `Seq[T <: Data]` and then construct a `Vec` out of that. The `Vec` object has two main apply methods: a varargs one and a seq. [For your own reference, take a look at the Chisel `Vec` object API documentation](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/package$$Vec$.html).

The following full example builds, but the relevant part is the `val pipe` and `val pipe2` lines. You can do this with either a `map` or a `for`/`yield`.

```scala
import chisel3._

import chisel3.util.RegEnable
import chisel3.iotesters
import chisel3.experimental.MultiIOModule

class Example(len: Int) extends MultiIOModule {
  val in = Seq.fill(len)(IO(Input(UInt(1.W))))
  val en = Seq.fill(len)(IO(Input(Bool())))

  val mySeq: Seq[Data] = (0 until len).map( j => RegEnable(in(j), en(j)) )
  val pipe = Vec(mySeq)

  val mySeq2: Seq[Data] = for (j <- 0 until len) yield ( RegEnable(in(j), en(j)) )
  val pipe2 = Vec(mySeq2)
}
```